# does iOS deletes NSTemporaryDirectory files when app is running in the background

Tags: ios

Can anybody please help me out if the files of NSTemporaryDirectory gets deleted when app is running in background because every where it is written that files will persist in this directory as long as the app is running but here it is not clear if it is the same behaviour in background also.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If the OS becomes starved on disk space, and your app is in the background, I imagine that the OS would kill your app, (like the OS says it can and will at any time while in the background), and then recover your temp directory space.

Answer (score 0):

No, `NSTemporaryDirectory` will not get deleted in background. iOS automatically clean temporary directories when needed. So, there is nothing like in background `NSTemporaryDirectory` get cleared or deleted.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but i am still not clear if the files in NSTemporaryDirectory directory will get deleted when app is moved to background that is it is running but inactive or what happens to these files when device runs low space in inactive state